# Reed Switch alternative IC, AMR or TMR

Tags: arduino, i2c, electromagnetism, reed-switch, position-sensor

I have a prototype that I have built which has 4 positional reed switches arranged in a square around a circle. There is a rotating magnet as shown below:

[image]

I would like to replace them with solid state components and so far I have gone from using TMR (tunnelling magnetoresistive) to AMR (Anisotropic Magneto Resistive) ICs, an example is [MMC5603NJ](https://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/MEMSIC%20PDFs/MMC5603NJ_RevB_7-12-18.pdf). They must have low sleep current in the low microamps or nano amp range and I only require a digital signal, which can be open drain or over I2C bus, be smallest possible footprint and low unit price. Would this be a suitable option  or am I missing a better option?

Aiming for WLSP package with price between $0.5 and $1.

Comment: If a simple mechanical or optical rotary encoder is not an option you might look into some Hall Effect sensors from ROHM, they have some very low cost lead-less parts.

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't give specifics on size or price, I can't say for certain but specific product recommendations aren't allowed here anyways (for good reason), so I'll just say that a cursory search of Hall effect sensors shows that you'll probably find one that suits your needs.

Comment: Hi @vir Sorry. I am looking for WLSP package with price around 0.5 Cents but unto $1. Thank you.